# Have any prominent critics of the Bhaviṣya Purāṇa explained the second references to Christianity and Islam?

Tags: guru, other-religions, bhavishya-purana, future

A common criticism of the Bhaviṣya Purāṇa is that it was written after the prophecies for Christianity and Islam.

I don't find this at all convincing, because the Bhaviṣya Purāṇa references them at least twice and the second ones are clearly in the future, so the Bhaviṣya Purāṇa obviously could not be written before them. They are:

This is a refrence to Christianity, specifically the four horses of the four horsemen of the apocalypse. You can tell this clearly from the colours:

> Which cause divine Harinee to produce pale colored male horse named Manoratha (Manohaaraa) and black colored male horse named Karaala (frightful). The both came same time from that single womb and they were part of Shabya (one of the warrior in Mahabharata) and Sugriva (important character in Ramayana). After that from the part of Jishnu and Vishnu there took birth two horses from the womb of Harinee. One is Meghapushpa (divine name), which is golden in color and was named Bindulaa (Bendulaa) and other is Balahaak (divine name) which is white in color like snow and was named Harinagara. This were the first four horses produced from the divine horse Harinee and Papihaa and from those four divine flying horses, many horses took birth later. Thus I have explained to you Munis! How those four divine flying horses took birth. "

This reference to Muhammad is clearly in the future as it ties in to the main story that makes no sense not being in the future (it goes on for a bit longer, but this is the most important part):

> Shobhana then fell down to the ground senseless. Thereafter getting back to her senses, started to cry loudly and said: - “How could I get that handsome Krishnaamsa? What could I do without him? Where will I go?" Thus saying those words in grief, she arrived the place named Madhinapura (Medina). There that resident, the great illusionist Mahaamada (Muhammad) who was involved in the works of “Pisacha" (ghastly works of a ghost). She made herself to sacrifice her life infront of him. Seeing her, and being pleased, he visited the temple of Marusthalesvara (the lord of desert) which consist of a Linga of Mahadeva (lord Shiva) and started to worship the lord with Sanskrit words. Being pleased with his servant, Lord Shiva appeared and said: - “The woman named Svarnavatee had kidnapped that Krishnaamsa who is staunch Aryan culture follower and very much gallant. Therefore, my servant, please do come with me in the place named “Mayurnagara" “.

Thus deciding not to trust the Bhaviṣya Purāṇa based on it not being before its prophecies does not make sense and also the first references to both religions could be simply for context. Thus, does any expert on Hinduism or a notable Hindu guru have a criticism of the Bhaviṣya Purāṇa that acknowledges that the Bhaviṣya Purāṇa references Christianity and Islam twice.

Comment: First of all a mention of 4 divine horses doesn't necessarily mean that it is a reference to a Christianity, it looks similar doesn't mean they're the same thing. In Christianity these "Divine" horses cause the end of the world.

These two blogs talk about Muhammed in the Puranas, do read https://www.bhavishyapurana.com/

https://prophetmohammedpbum.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/bhavishya-purana-prediction-of-muhammad-debunking-islamic-polemicists-dr-zakir-naik-and-mushafiq-sultan/

Comment: @SaffronVajra In the Bhaviṣya Purāṇa, Krshna gives a boon to Kali (after he prays to him) to take birth to protect Kali. Thus one incarnation of Vishnu does cause "the end of the world," and it is probably Harinagara fitting into his description in Christianity. Also, the colours matching would be pretty unlikely a coincidence, especially considering Vishnu is usually depicted as blue.

Comment: @SaffronVajra As for Muhammad, the two blogs you mentioned do the common mistake of only referring to the first reference, which misses out a lot of the point of what the Bhaviṣya Purāṇa is telling you about Muhammad and Islam.

Comment: Yes but do these "horses" end the world? Also the horses had 4 horsemen on them.

Critics can easily explain this, they can easily say it's an interpolation, I mean you BELIEVE in Hinduism thus you think it's future predictions, which doesn't hold value critically.

Comment: @SaffronVajra Even if I didn't believe in Hinduism, it would be a future prediction, as it is in the FUTURE. The horses have horsemen in the main story and likely cause the end of the world as I explained before.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaticinium_ex_eventu